# Webpack get base modules loaded for global use

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, jquery-select2

I have a project where I use Select2 (and other things) that needs jQuery. I try to create my frontend with Webpack, but it is loaded as several different javascript files (so my webpack config shows multiple module exports). To get jQuery/$ to work correctly when packing the files I added the following:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
    }),
]
```

And my select2_creator.js would look a bit like:

```
import 'select2'

$(function() {
    $("#id_dropdown_1").select2({dropdownAutoWidth: true});
    $("#id_dropdown_2").select2({dropdownAutoWidth: true});
});
```

This worked, but now I wanted to nicely take jQuery and install it instead of having a static jquery.min.js in my folder. Therefore I created a new js file that only had:
`import jquery`
With the idea that that js file named main_bundles.js would then work as jQuery (and later as other libraries that are used everywhere in the project).
The main_bundles.js is created and I import it in the front end with (django template):

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "custom_js/main_bundles.js" %}"></script>`

But now the front end does not seem to "see" that jQuery is there at all and I get the $ is undefined error.
And most likely I just don't understand well enough how JavaScript goes about library management and what is and is not global, but in all honesty I also cannot find the right documentation it seems to explain to me. How do I fix this in the "best practices/correct" way?